# Tangent Plane and parallel plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here is the question: At what point on the parabloid $y=x^2+z^2$ is the tangent plane parallel to $x+2y+3z=1$.

I have computed the tangent plane to be

$$T(x,z) = f(x_0,z_0) + 2x_0(x-x_0) + 2z_o(z-z_0)$$

My question is how do i go about finding this point?

Comment: the two planes have to have the same normal

Comment: How can they have the same normal if the normal of the f(x,y) only contains 2 dependent variables?

Comment: your formula for $T$ is wrong, they should be stated differently

Comment: What is wrong? is y not a dependent variable?

Comment: Rename $T(x,z)$ as $y$ and then the coefficients on $x$, $y$, and $z$ (after moving them all over to one side) will be a normal vector.  When the normals are parallel, the planes will be parallel.

Comment: Ok I understand now.